# Datepicker function (count days between 2 dates)not working after call ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onselect

I have 2 datepickers to count days between them:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker({    
        onSelect: showDays
    });
});

function showDays() {
    var start = $('#datepicker2').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#datepicker3').datepicker('getDate');

    if (!start || !end) 
        return;

    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    $('#totaldays').val(days);
}
```

This works. Now the problem is with the next AJAX request the function `showDays()` stops working. I tried this inside `success` as others answers here suggest, but it still does not work.

```
$("#datepicker3").datepicker({
    onSelect: showDays
});
```

The AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ///PARA SELECCIONAR NUMERO DE HABITACION
    $('#id_residencial').on('change', function() {
        var id_residencial = $(this).val();
        if (id_residencial) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'get_id_habitacion.php',
                data: 'id_residencial='+id_residencial,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#id_habitacion').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

SOLUTION:

I put `$('.datepicker3').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        ///PARA SELECCIONAR NUMERO DE HABITACION
        $('#id_residencial').on('change', function() {
            var id_residencial = $(this).val();
            if (id_residencial) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'get_id_habitacion.php',
                    data: 'id_residencial='+id_residencial,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#id_habitacion').html(html);
                        $('.datepicker3').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker();
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
    });
```

And it´s working :)

Comment: If any of the datepickers is inside the `#id_habitacion` element, you need to bind these manually in the success function.

Comment: to add to @jeroen 's comment - this must be *after* you set the `.html()` - can you show in the question exactly where you tried to add it "inside success"

Comment: I put $('.datepicker3').not('.hasDatePicker').datepicker(); in success and it´s working